# Getting the Max value in all [x] indexes in a list of lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, max

If I have a `List<List<double>>` object in the C# project, how could I get the largest value of all [x] indexes in each List in that object?

To clarify my idea, if I have the object:

```
List<List<double>> myList = ......
```

and if the values of the [10] index in each list in myList are:

```
myList[0][10] = 5;
myList[1][10] = 15;
myList[2][10] = 1;
myList[3][10] = 3;
myList[4][10] = 7;
myList[5][10] = 5;
```

So, I need to get the value **15** since it is the max of them.

Thanks,
Regards.
Aya

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "of all [x] indexes"? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use following for maximum index value

```
List<List<double>> list = ...
var maxIndex = list.Max( innerList => innerList.Count - 1); // Gets the Maximum index value.
```

If you want maximum value, you can use

```
 var maxValue = list.Max ( innerList => innerList.Max());
```

See also [Enumerable.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549404.aspx)

---

**EDIT** as per comments

> I need the max value of those in a specific index in each list.

An unoptimized solution is to use following query.

```
var index = 10;
var maxAtIndex10 = list.Max ( innerList => innerList[index]);
```

Following query is to find max at all indexes.

```
var maxIndex = list.Max( innerList => innerList.Count);
var listMaxAtAllIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0,maxIndex).Select ( index => list.Max(innerList => index < innerList.Count ? innerList[index] : 0));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I won't want the max value of each list. Instead, I need the max value of those in a specific index in each list.